# Expand descriptions for Selenium WebDriver parser (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, parsing, selenium

I'm trying to expand descriptions in the search result. I need to click the "More" link for every result for resolving my task.

Link - https://www.odesk.com/o/profiles/browse/?q=ios

I try to use:

```
table = @driver.find_element(:xpath, "html/body/div[1]/article/form/div/div")
table.find_elements(:css, ".oMore").each(&:click)
```

All "More" elements are expanded but the browser goes to Registration form, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Does this problem always occur? What browser are you using? I have not been able to reproduce the problem. But my guess is that one of the "More" links is being clicked while it is under the registration button. Since the element on top is the registration button, you go to that page. I know this type of problem exists as I have seen it on another page, but like I said, I cannot seem to reproduce the same here.

Comment: The problem always occurs. I'm using FF. What browser did you use?

Comment: I am using Firefox too. Apparently, I was not able to reproduce the problem yesterday because I was using Selenium-Webdriver 2.39.0. After upgrading to version 2.40.0 (ie latest), I can now see the problem too.

Comment: I just checked the xpath of first line. The xpath contains the search result and the left sidebar but should contain only the search result. I can check this during 2-3 hours

Answer (score -1):

The issue is resolved. In my case I needed to update FF to last version (28.0). Maybe it's bug in WebDriver or FF.

But the problem is still reproducible in IE10